# How to open google Drive interface in a browser

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to open the Google Drive interface "www.drive.goole..." from an app in Java using a service account. The service account works fine, I can acces to my files, insert .... But I need to open the google interface **without login** in google, only with the service account.

It is possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. Its completely different things using a service account and opening the web browser interface of drive.
You could write your own web interface to drive and use the service account thou but I dont think thats what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I feared That answer .... is there any possibility of doing this, even another way?

Comment: the only way I can think is the one I suggested in the answer, you write your own drive interface to display and interact with drive, and use the service account to get/set the necessary data. Of course its a big project to implement all the features, and some cant be even implemented since the drive sdk doesnt expose all the functionality that drive.google.com does (in particular sorting files other than by modified without having to request the entire result set).